# Realm android application crash: io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. mmap() failed: Out of memory size

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I am evaluating Realm database(Android) for my next project. I decided to write a test application to insert 1 million objects and check the performance of Realm database. The test application is a simple android app. 
Users can specify the amount of random objects of a particular model class to be created and the objects are created in an IntentService in the background. As and when objects are created, the activity displays the total number of objects in the realm.

IntentService which is used to create random objects.

```
package example.com.realmcrashapplication;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.realm.Realm;

public class BackendService extends IntentService {

public static final String TASK_DETAILS = "taskDetails";
public static final String INSERTION_COUNT = "insertionCount";    
private static final int insertsPerTransaction = 1000;
private int remainingInsertions = 0;

public BackendService() {
    super(BackendService.class.getName());
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra(TASK_DETAILS);
    if(args != null) {
        if(args.containsKey(INSERTION_COUNT)){
            final int count = args.getInt(INSERTION_COUNT);
            if(count>0){
                remainingInsertions = count;
                while(remainingInsertions>0){
                    final int c;
                    if(remainingInsertions>insertsPerTransaction){
                        c=insertsPerTransaction;
                    }else{
                        c=remainingInsertions;
                    }
                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    final Person p = Person.getRandomPerson();
                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            for(int i=0;i<c;++i) {
                                realm.copyToRealm(p);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    realm.close();
                    remainingInsertions-=c;
                }
            }

        }
    }
 }

}
```

Whenever I try to create more than 100k objects(my goal is to create 1 million objects),  the application crashes with the following error.Note:The memory consumption(as seen from Android Monitor) varies from 8.0MB to 11MB during insertions.

```
example.com.realmcrashapplication D/REALM:   jni: ThrowingException 11, mmap() failed: Out of memory size: 671088640 offset:   0 in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 188, .
example.com.realmcrashapplication D/REALM:   Exception has been throw: Unrecoverable error. mmap() failed: Out of memory size: 671088640 offset: 0 in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 188
example.com.realmcrashapplication W/dalvikvm: threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bc2c08)
example.com.realmcrashapplication  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:   IntentService[example.com.realmcrashapplication.BackendService]
                                                                                        Process: example.com.realmcrashapplication, PID: 27140
                                                                                         io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. mmap() failed: Out of memory size: 671088640 offset: 0 in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 188
                                                                                          at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.nativeCommitAndContinueAsRead(Native Method)
                                                                                         at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.commitAndContinueAsRead(SharedGroup.java:149)
                                                                                         at io.realm.internal.ImplicitTransaction.commitAndContinueAsRead(ImplicitTransaction.java:62)
                                                                                         at io.realm.internal.SharedGroupManager.commitAndContinueAsRead(SharedGroupManager.java:118)
                                                                                         at io.realm.BaseRealm.commitTransaction(BaseRealm.java:362)
                                                                                         at io.realm.BaseRealm.commitTransaction(BaseRealm.java:349)
                                                                                         at io.realm.Realm.commitTransaction(Realm.java:121)
                                                                                         at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:967)
                                                                                         at example.com.realmcrashapplication.BackendService.onHandleIntent(BackendService.java:42)
                                                                                         at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I have tried reducing the number of insertions per transactions from 1000 to 10, but the result is same.I have enough space in my Phone. So its not about storage I guess. The file size after 100K insertions crosses 600MB(Its 704MB after 145K objects)

Realm Library 1.0.1 Android Java

Tested on : Samsung Galaxy Note 2 Android 4.4.2 API 19.

Model classes

**Person**

```
package example.com.realmcrashapplication;

import java.util.Date;
import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class Person extends RealmObject{
private int field1;
private String field2;
private Date field3;
private String field4;
private Date field5;
private String field6;
private String field7;
private int field8;
private double field9;
private String field10;
private int field11;
private int field12;
private double field13;
private double field14;
private int field15;
private String field16;
private double field17;
private boolean field18;
private String field19;
private double field20;
private boolean field21;
private boolean field22;
private int field23;
private ExtraInfo1 field24;
private ExtraInfo1 field25;
private ExtraInfo1 field26;
private ExtraInfo1 field27;
private ExtraInfo1 field28;
private RealmList<ExtraInfo2> field29;
private Integer field30;
private String field31;
private String field32;
private String field33;
private String field34;
private String field35;
private String field36;
private Address field37;
private boolean field38;
private Date field39;
private int field40;
private int field41;
private double field42;
private double field43;
private String field44;
private String field45;
private String field46;
private Address field47;
private int field48;
private String field49;
private Date field50;
private String field51;
private boolean field52;
private RealmList<ExtraInfo3> field53;
private double field54;
private double field55;
private double field56;
private RealmList<Person> family;

public void setField1(int field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}
public void setField2(String field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}
public void setField3(Date field3) {
    this.field3 = field3;
}
public void setField4(String field4) {
    this.field4 = field4;
}
public void setField5(Date field5) {
    this.field5 = field5;
}
public void setField6(String field6) {
    this.field6 = field6;
}
public void setField7(String field7) {
    this.field7 = field7;
}
public void setField8(int field8) {
    this.field8 = field8;
}
public void setField9(double field9) {
    this.field9 = field9;
}
public void setField10(String field10) {
    this.field10 = field10;
}
public void setField11(int field11) {
    this.field11 = field11;
}
public void setField12(int field12) {
    this.field12 = field12;
}
public void setField13(double field13) {
    this.field13 = field13;
}
public void setField14(double field14) {
    this.field14 = field14;
}
public void setField15(int field15) {
    this.field15 = field15;
}
public void setField16(String field16) {
    this.field16 = field16;
}
public void setField17(double field17) {
    this.field17 = field17;
}
public void setField18(boolean field18) {
    this.field18 = field18;
}
public void setField19(String field19) {
    this.field19 = field19;
}
public void setField20(double field20) {
    this.field20 = field20;
}
public void setField21(boolean field21) {
    this.field21 = field21;
}
public void setField22(boolean field22) {
    this.field22 = field22;
}
public void setField23(int field23) {
    this.field23 = field23;
}
public void setField24(ExtraInfo1 field24) {
    this.field24 = field24;
}
public void setField25(ExtraInfo1 field25) {
    this.field25 = field25;
}
public void setField26(ExtraInfo1 field26) {
    this.field26 = field26;
}
public void setField27(ExtraInfo1 field27) {
    this.field27 = field27;
}
public void setField28(ExtraInfo1 field28) {
    this.field28 = field28;
}
public void setField29(RealmList<ExtraInfo2> field29) {
    this.field29 = field29;
}
public void setField30(Integer field30) {
    this.field30 = field30;
}
public void setField31(String field31) {
    this.field31 = field31;
}
public void setField32(String field32) {
    this.field32 = field32;
}
public void setField33(String field33) {
    this.field33 = field33;
}
public void setField34(String field34) {
    this.field34 = field34;
}
public void setField35(String field35) {
    this.field35 = field35;
}
public void setField36(String field36) {
    this.field36 = field36;
}
public void setField37(Address field37) {
    this.field37 = field37;
}
public void setField38(boolean field38) {
    this.field38 = field38;
}
public void setField39(Date field39) {
    this.field39 = field39;
}
public void setField40(int field40) {
    this.field40 = field40;
}
public void setField41(int field41) {
    this.field41 = field41;
}
public void setField42(double field42) {
    this.field42 = field42;
}
public void setField43(double field43) {
    this.field43 = field43;
}
public void setField44(String field44) {
    this.field44 = field44;
}
public void setField45(String field45) {
    this.field45 = field45;
}
public void setField46(String field46) {
    this.field46 = field46;
}
public void setField47(Address field47) {
    this.field47 = field47;
}
public void setField48(int field48) {
    this.field48 = field48;
}
public void setField49(String field49) {
    this.field49 = field49;
}
public void setField50(Date field50) {
    this.field50 = field50;
}
public void setField51(String field51) {
    this.field51 = field51;
}
public void setField52(boolean field52) {
    this.field52 = field52;
}
public void setField53(RealmList<ExtraInfo3> field53) {
    this.field53 = field53;
}
public void setField54(double field54) {
    this.field54 = field54;
}
public void setField55(double field55) {
    this.field55 = field55;
}
public void setField56(double field56) {
    this.field56 = field56;
}
public void setFamily(RealmList<Person> family) {
    this.family = family;
}
public static Person getRandomPerson(){
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setField1(9);
    p.setField2(HelperClass.getRandomString(15));
    p.setField3(HelperClass.getRandomDate());
    p.setField4(HelperClass.getRandomString(15));
    p.setField5(HelperClass.getRandomDate());
    p.setField6(HelperClass.getRandomString(24));
    p.setField7(HelperClass.getRandomString(100));
    p.setField8(9);
    p.setField9(0.567);
    p.setField10(HelperClass.getRandomString(3));
    p.setField11(9);
    p.setField12(1);
    p.setField13(45.00);
    p.setField14(0);
    p.setField15(1);
    p.setField16(HelperClass.getRandomString(15));
    p.setField17(5);
    p.setField18(true);
    p.setField19(HelperClass.getRandomString(15));
    p.setField20(5);
    p.setField21(true);
    p.setField22(true);
    p.setField23(5);
    p.setField24(ExtraInfo1.getRandomExtraInfo1());
    p.setField25(ExtraInfo1.getRandomExtraInfo1());
    p.setField26(ExtraInfo1.getRandomExtraInfo1());
    p.setField27(ExtraInfo1.getRandomExtraInfo1());
    p.setField28(ExtraInfo1.getRandomExtraInfo1());

    RealmList<ExtraInfo2> extraInfo2Items = new RealmList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ExtraInfo2 extraInfo2 = ExtraInfo2.getRandomExtraInfo2();
        extraInfo2Items.add(extraInfo2);
    }
    p.setField29(extraInfo2Items);
    p.setField30(1);
    p.setField31(HelperClass.getRandomString(24));
    p.setField32(HelperClass.getRandomString(24));
    p.setField33(HelperClass.getRandomString(10));
    p.setField34(HelperClass.getRandomString(10));
    p.setField35(HelperClass.getRandomString(128));
    p.setField36(HelperClass.getRandomString(10));
    p.setField37(Address.getRandomAddress());
    p.setField38(true);
    p.setField39(HelperClass.getRandomDate());
    p.setField40(1);
    p.setField41(1);
    p.setField42(10);
    p.setField43(0.00);
    p.setField44(HelperClass.getRandomString(24));
    p.setField45(HelperClass.getRandomString(100));
    p.setField46(HelperClass.getRandomString(30));
    p.setField47(Address.getRandomAddress());
    p.setField48(30);
    p.setField49(HelperClass.getRandomString(30));
    p.setField50(HelperClass.getRandomDate());
    p.setField51(HelperClass.getRandomString(100));
    p.setField52(true);

    RealmList<ExtraInfo3> extraInfo3List = new RealmList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        ExtraInfo3 extraInfo3 = ExtraInfo3.getRandomExtraInfo3();
        extraInfo3List.add(extraInfo3);
    }
    p.setField53(extraInfo3List);
    p.setField54(100);
    p.setField55(100);
    p.setField56(0);
    return p;
}
}
```

**Address**

```
package example.com.realmcrashapplication;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Random;
import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class Address extends RealmObject{
private String line1;
private String line2;
private String zip;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private int type;

public String getLine1() {
    return line1;
}

public void setLine1(String line1) {
    this.line1 = line1;
}

public String getLine2() {
    return line2;
}

public void setLine2(String line2) {
    this.line2 = line2;
}

public String getZip() {
    return zip;
}

public void setZip(String zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public static Address getRandomAddress(){
    Address a = new Address();
    a.setLine1(HelperClass.getRandomString(49));
    a.setLine2(HelperClass.getRandomString(49));
    a.setZip(HelperClass.getRandomString(10));
    a.setCity(HelperClass.getRandomString(24));
    a.setState(HelperClass.getRandomString(20));
    a.setCountry(HelperClass.getRandomString(30));
    a.setType(1);
    return a;
}
}
```

**ExtraInfo1**

```
package example.com.realmcrashapplication;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class ExtraInfo1 extends RealmObject {
private String field1;
private boolean field2;
private int field3;
private int field4;
private double field5;
private double field6;
private int field7;
private boolean field8;
private String field9;
private double field10;
private String field11;
private double field12;
private boolean field13;

public void setField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}
public void setField2(boolean field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}
public void setField3(int field3) {
    this.field3 = field3;
}
public void setField4(int field4) {
    this.field4 = field4;
}
public void setField5(double field5) {
    this.field5 = field5;
}
public void setField6(double field6) {
    this.field6 = field6;
}
public void setField7(int field7) {
    this.field7 = field7;
}
public void setField8(boolean field8) {
    this.field8 = field8;
}
public void setField9(String field9) {
    this.field9 = field9;
}
public void setField10(double field10) {
    this.field10 = field10;
}
public void setField11(String field11) {
    this.field11 = field11;
}
public void setField12(double field12) {
    this.field12 = field12;
}
public void setField13(boolean field13) {
    this.field13 = field13;
}

public static ExtraInfo1 getRandomExtraInfo1(){
    ExtraInfo1 info = new ExtraInfo1();
    info.setField1(HelperClass.getRandomString(10));
    info.setField2(true);
    info.setField3(1);
    info.setField4(1);
    info.setField5(0);
    info.setField6(0);
    info.setField7(1);
    info.setField8(true);
    info.setField9(HelperClass.getRandomString(15));
    info.setField10(5);
    info.setField11(HelperClass.getRandomString(15));
    info.setField12(5);
    info.setField13(true);
    return info;
}
}
```

**ExtraInfo2**

```
package example.com.realmcrashapplication;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class ExtraInfo2 extends RealmObject {
private int field1;
private String field2;
private double field3;
private boolean field4;
private double field5;
private String field6;
private double field7;
private int field8;
private double field9;
private double field10;
private String field11;
private boolean field12;
private String field13;
private double field14;
private String field15;
private double field16;
private boolean field17;

public void setField1(int field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}
public void setField2(String field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}

public void setField3(double field3) {
    this.field3 = field3;
}
public void setField4(boolean field4) {
    this.field4 = field4;
}
public void setField5(double field5) {
    this.field5 = field5;
}
public void setField6(String field6) {
    this.field6 = field6;
}
public void setField7(double field7) {
    this.field7 = field7;
}
public void setField8(int field8) {
    this.field8 = field8;
}
public void setField9(double field9) {
    this.field9 = field9;
}

public void setField10(double field10) {
    this.field10 = field10;
}
public void setField11(String field11) {
    this.field11 = field11;
}
public void setField12(boolean field12) {
    this.field12 = field12;
}
public void setField13(String field13) {
    this.field13 = field13;
}
public void setField14(double field14) {
    this.field14 = field14;
}
public void setField15(String field15) {
    this.field15 = field15;
}
public void setField16(double field16) {
    this.field16 = field16;
}
public void setField17(boolean field17) {
    this.field17 = field17;
}

public static ExtraInfo2 getRandomExtraInfo2(){
    ExtraInfo2 extraInfo2 = new ExtraInfo2();
    extraInfo2.setField1(1);
    extraInfo2.setField2(HelperClass.getRandomString(15));
    extraInfo2.setField3(18.0);
    extraInfo2.setField4(true);
    extraInfo2.setField5(9.0);
    extraInfo2.setField6("value");
    extraInfo2.setField7(1.0);
    extraInfo2.setField8(1);
    extraInfo2.setField9(0.0);
    extraInfo2.setField10(0.0);
    extraInfo2.setField11(HelperClass.getRandomString(100));
    extraInfo2.setField12(true);
    extraInfo2.setField13(HelperClass.getRandomString(15));
    extraInfo2.setField14(5);
    extraInfo2.setField15(HelperClass.getRandomString(15));
    extraInfo2.setField16(5);
    extraInfo2.setField17(true);
    return extraInfo2;
}
}
```

**ExtraInfo3**

```
package example.com.realmcrashapplication;

import java.util.Date;
import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class ExtraInfo3 extends RealmObject {
private Date field1;
private int field2;
private String field3;
private double field4;
private String field5;
private String field6;

public void setField1(Date field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}
public void setField2(int field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}
public void setField3(String field3) {
    this.field3 = field3;
}
public void setField4(double field4) {
    this.field4 = field4;
}
public void setField5(String field5) {
    this.field5 = field5;
}
public void setField6(String field6) {
    this.field6 = field6;
}

public static ExtraInfo3 getRandomExtraInfo3(){
    ExtraInfo3 extraInfo3 = new ExtraInfo3();
    extraInfo3.setField1(HelperClass.getRandomDate());
    extraInfo3.setField2(1);
    extraInfo3.setField3(HelperClass.getRandomString(10));
    extraInfo3.setField4(10.00);
    extraInfo3.setField5(HelperClass.getRandomString(10));
    extraInfo3.setField6(HelperClass.getRandomString(24));
    return extraInfo3;
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package example.com.realmcrashapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmChangeListener;
import io.realm.RealmResults;
import io.realm.Sort;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Realm realm;
    private RealmResults<Person> persons;
    private RealmChangeListener personsChangeListener;
    private TextView personCountTextView;
    private Intent backgroundIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        personCountTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.personCountText);
        TextView locationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationText);
        locationText.setText(MyApplication.location);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                InsertPersonsDialogFragment newFragment = new InsertPersonsDialogFragment();
                newFragment.setClickListener(new InsertPersonsDialogFragment.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInsertItems(int count) {
                        insertPersons(count);
                    }
                });
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "insertPersonsDialog");
            }
        });
        backgroundIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackendService.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        persons = realm.where(Person.class).findAllSortedAsync("field3", Sort.DESCENDING);
        personsChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Person>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(final RealmResults<Person> personsList) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(personCountTextView!=null) {
                            String size = Integer.toString(personsList.size());
                            personCountTextView.setText("Number of persons : "+size);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        };
        persons.addChangeListener(personsChangeListener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(personsChangeListener!=null){
            realm.removeChangeListener(personsChangeListener);
        }
        realm.close();
    }
    private void insertPersons(final int count) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(BackendService.INSERTION_COUNT, count);
        backgroundIntent.putExtra(BackendService.TASK_DETAILS, args);
        startService(backgroundIntent);
    }
}
```

**MyApplication**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static String location = "";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        File dir = new File("/sdcard/realm2");
        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        location = dir.getAbsolutePath();
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(dir).
                                                    deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().
                                                    build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Samsung Galaxy Note 2 is a 32 bit device, and `mmap()` is often limited to 300-600 MB on 32 bit Android.

Comment: @geisshirt If this is the case, I have to split my data between a number of realm files. Am I right?

Comment: Here at Realm, are we fully aware of this limitation, and we are currently working on changing our `mmap()` usage patterns. I can't promise when the fix will be out.

Comment: @geisshirt Thanks for the info

Comment: @geisshirt , Please do fix this issue. Its really a big problem for us.

Comment: The fix mentioned in my comment above was released with Realm Java 1.1.1 by reducing the number of files used. The limitation of `mmap()` and Android is out of the scope of Realm.